# How to separate images having different dimensions stored in list in python

Tags: python, list

I am having a ***list(Cyst_intensity)*** of length `l`containing values of contour area of images in the dimension `(n x 3)`. i.e list of lists.

Where `3` represents the three channels and `n` represents the rows having image values.

[image]

I want to store the ***Red ,Blue, Green*** channel separately in a list.

```
# Cyst pixel generator
cyst_intensity= []

# For each list of contour points...
for i in range(len(cystcontours)):
    # Create a mask image that contains the contour filled in
    cimg = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv.drawContours(cimg, cystcontours, i, color=255, thickness=-1)

    # Access the image pixels and create a 1D numpy array then add to list
    pts = np.where(cimg == 255)
    #Cyst_intensity will contain the original image contour pixel value  
    cyst_intensity.append(image[pts[0], pts[1]])

#separating into channels and averaging out 
B=[]
G=[]
R=[]
cystcolours=[]
i=0
for m in iter(cyst_intensity):
    for j in m[i][0]:
        B.append(j)
        i+=1
    i=0
    for k in m[i][1]:
        G.append(k)
        i+=1
    i=0
    for q in m[i][2]:
        R.append(q)
        i+=1
    cystcolours.append([avg(B),avg(G),avg(R)])
```

I am getting the following error when i run the above code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 7, in <module>    
TypeError: 'numpy.uint8' object is not iterable
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: what is `cyst_intensity` in your code and where is your full traceback? in current state your snippet does not look like [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Cyst_intensity(list name) containing the list of images having (n x 3 ) dimension.

Comment: that's great, but how can anyone reproduce your error with incomplete code given?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough i dont know how you store images, i suggest your image is stored as kx3 where k is a pixel. Your mistake is that m[i][j] is a single value not an array and i think that is your mistake. So if you want to iterate through all of the rows of the image you should do something like this.

```
for image in cyst_identity:
 for pixel in image:
  R.append(pixel[0])
  G.append(pixel[1])
  B.append(pixel[2])
 #get average here. Outside the inner loop
```

If you store each image is of type nxn, where each cell of these 2D array is a pixel then the above wont work. I cant replicate the problem since the information was kinda incomplete for a definite answer.

Comment: hey thank you, this solved the problem, by calling list on the append part of the code did the trick.